# MySQL Full Text Search: Why does MATCH AGAINST not utilize table indexes

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am experimenting with MySQL full-text search and have encountered something I cannot get my head around.

When writing a standard query for finding an article with a certain language 
and a given word (e.g. Trump) is in the content of the article I would write something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (select * from article WHERE language_id = 2) AS A 
WHERE content like '%Trump%';
```

Here MySQL utilizes the index on `language_id` to narrow 
it down and then goes through the inner select and does the LIKE clause

This goes pretty fast since there are only ~400 articles (out of 900K) that have language_id with 2.

However, when I try and do the same with a MATCH AGAINST clause it runs much slower:

```
SELECT *
from (select * from article  WHERE language_id = 2) as A
where MATCH(content) AGAINST ('Trump');
```

Why is this? Is MySQL not utilizing the index on language_id when it's a full_text search? Is there any way to speed up the query given that I want to search only in the subset of the DB that has `language_id = 2`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why that would work, but did you try to use `join` instead of an inner select? Does that make a difference?

Comment: We tried doing a join instead of an inner select. This unfortunately still resulted in a slower query than with the like clause